# Sitecore detect Australian state using GeoLocaton

Tags: geo-location

Noticed that  Tracker.Current.Interaction.GeoData object doesn't have state property. However it has Region, City, Postalcode etc.

We have requirement to identify visitor state so and personalize the content.

On top of this we have requirement to identify state of visitor and use it for website business rules.

Wondering if there's an easy way to achieve this with out of box Geo location API and how reliable it is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### No, not out of the box.

According to Sitecore, there is no way to upgrade the precision on the Geo IP services provided. Out of the box, they state:

> Inaccuracy in country, state, and city resolving. Sitecore IP Geolocation service may provide limited precision on a country, state, and city level.

[For Australia](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-accuracy-comparison?country=Australia&resolution=50), the precision of the service is around 66%.

Full list of precision by country, here: [GeoIP2 City Accuracy](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city-accuracy-comparison)

### Recommendation

Build your own, if you need better precision.

> If the precision of the Sitecore IP Geolocation Service is not acceptable due to business reasons, a custom provider could be implemented to connect Sitecore with any other system for resolving Geo IP data.

Source: [Sitecore IP Geolocation Service accuracy](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/569970)

Comment: Thanks, what are the options we could use without us having to spend lots of time and reinvent?

Comment: I don't know. There are dozens of providers out there, but I don't know of any one specific that would offer a higher precision than what Maxmind's GeoIP2 already offers.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to personalize by Australian State,'Region' is usually the 'State' (or 'Province', depending on country). Mark is right about data accuracy, but if you are just looking to pull what it THINKS the State is, you would usually personalize to Region.